# Wordpress theme contact form not working

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contact-form

I recently offered to help a friend with his under-development website, but I got stuck in the contact form. Although the form passes validation (in theory), the form is not sent out.
As it is right now, I have narrowed it down to the following function, specifically the 2nd foreach loop... Looks like the field values come up empty...
Here is the function, complete...:

```
function send()
        {
            $new_post = array();

            foreach ($_POST as $key => $post) 
            {
                $new_post[str_replace('form_','',$key)] = $post;
            }

            $mymail     = empty($this->form_parameters['myemail']) ? $new_post['myemail'] : $this->form_parameters['myemail'];
            $myblogname = empty($this->form_parameters['myblogname']) ? $new_post['myblogname'] : $this->form_parameters['myblogname'];
            $subject    = empty($new_post['subject']) ? "New Message" : $new_post['subject'];

            $default_from = parse_url(home_url());

            //set the email adress
            $from = "no-reply@wp-message.com";
            $usermail = false;

            //if(!empty($default_from['host'])) $from = "no-reply@".$default_from['host'];

            if(!empty($this->autoresponder[0]))
            {
                $from = $_POST[$this->autoresponder[0]];
                $usermail = true;
            }
            else
            {
                $email_variations = array( 'e-mail', 'email', 'mail' );

                foreach($email_variations as $key)
                {
                    foreach ($new_post as $current_key => $current_post)
                    {
                        if( strpos($current_key, $key) !== false)
                        {
                            $from = $new_post[$current_key];
                            $usermail = true;
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    if($usermail == true) break;
                }
            }

            $to = urldecode( $mymail );
            $from = urldecode( $from );
            $subject = urldecode( $subject );
            $message = "";

            foreach($this->form_elements as $key => $element)
            {
                if(!empty($new_post[str_replace(" ", "_", preg_replace("[^A-Za-z]", "" ,$key))]))
                {
                        if($element['type'] == 'textarea') $message .= "<br/>";
                        $message .= $element['label'].": ".nl2br(urldecode($new_post[str_replace(" ", "_", preg_replace("[^A-Za-z]", "" ,$key))]))."<br/>";
                        if($element['type'] == 'textarea') $message .= "<br/>";
                }
                else { $message .= "error..."; }
            }

            $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
            $header .= 'From:'. $from . " \r\n";
            //wp_mail('gnikolopoulos@gmail.com', $subject, $message, $header);
            if(!wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)){
                $this->errors = true;
                return false;
            }

            if($usermail && !empty($this->form_parameters['autoresponder']))
            {
                $header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
                $header .= 'From:'. urldecode( $this->form_parameters['autoresponder_email']) . " \r\n";
                $message = nl2br($this->form_parameters['autoresponder'])."<br/><br/><br/><strong>Your Message:</strong><br/><br/>".$message;
                if(!wp_mail($from, $this->form_parameters['autoresponder_subject'], $message, $header)){
                    $this->errors = true;
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated....
FYI, I think he got this form from another theme than the one he is using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the

```
$new_post[str_replace('form_','',$key)] = $post;
```

line was causing the issue! The code was appending no prefix to the name of the form fields, so the str_replace function was failing.... As soon as I modified the code to actually include the desired prefix, everything worked just fine... Can't believe I did not see that one...!